# Can someone please explain what's wrong with this code?

Tags: java

This program does the following:
First input obtains two numbers from the user, second input if the user inputs (+) symbol the program adds the two numbers together, if the user enters (-) symbol it subtracts the 1st number from the 2nd number. 
But no results are shown the program just runs and terminates.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ObtainNumber {
public static void main(String []args) {

    String strNum1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number");
    String strNum2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number");

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(strNum1);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(strNum2);

    String askForOperation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What operation needs to be done?");

    int sum;
    if (askForOperation == "+") {
            sum = num1 + num2;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of the Addition is " + sum);
    }

    double subtract;
    if (askForOperation == "-") {
            subtract = num2 - num1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result of the subtraction is " + subtract);

    }



    }
```

}

Comment: Comparison of String...

Comment: use == '+' and == '-' since (+) and (-) are characters

Comment: The problem also is that it is a hacky Swing!

Comment: @MahmoudHashim no, they are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (askForOperation.equals("+")) {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   "The result of the Addition is " + sum);
}
```

To avoid any Nullpointer exception, in any case

do this,

```
final String plus = "+";
if (plus.equals(askForOperation)) {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   "The result of the Addition is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (askForOperation == "+")  // Reference is not same
```

Do the comparition check using `equals` method.

```
if ("+".equals(askForOperation))  // Compare content
```

Comment: While this is true, can you explain it little bit more? What is wrong with `==`?

Comment: == only check the reference whereas equals method compare the value.

Comment: I know that. Point in answering is not only to give solution, but also explain problem. Don't give fish, give rod and teach how to use it. Let OP learn *why* `==` is wrong here. Put your comment in your answer.

Comment: Sry cant understand @Pshemo the reference of askForOperation and + is not same

Comment: @fge i also say that reference is not same so need to use equals to compare the content

Answer (score 1):

This test:

```
askForOperation == "+"
```

is wrong. What is does is compare the *references* of `askForOperation` and (unnamed) string `"+"`, which is not the same at all.

You want to compare the contents; therefore you must use:

```
"+".equals(askForOperation)
```

Same for "-".

Sample:

```
String h1 = "hello";
String h2 = new String("hello");
h1 == h1; // true: same reference
h1 == h2; // false: different reference
h1.equals(h2); // true: same contents
```

Note that strings are a little special due to string literals -- `"+"` will "silently" create a `String` object for you, which is why you can write "strange-looking" code such as `"foo".equals(bar)`

Comment: @Pshemo gee, I keep forgetting about this one :/

Comment: That (because it works for interned literals) is probably main reason why people are trying to use `==` to compare all Strings  :/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(askForOperation.equals("+"){
    do smth..
}
```

Use of == for String is wrong,you must compare content like String1.equals(String2);

Comment: = for primitive types
equals -for objects

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    .equals
```

method insteed of ==

== compares the object reference and .equals compares value of the object value.

Comment: I asked what's wrong with the program if I had known the problem I would have Googled it

Comment: Ya sure @Korar F. sorry, I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will clear your doubt.

http://www.javabeat.net/what-is-difference-between-equals-and/